# Comment model only for user django (1048, “Column 'user_id' cannot be null” or no user filled)

Tags: python, django, comments

I hope you are well.

I'm trying to create comment for user with one form field (content). I'd like to have the user field automatically filled in user value.

I. I started with this model but I got an error **(1048, “Column 'user_id' cannot be null”)**:
models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

views.py

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView,FormMixin):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.post = self.object
            form.save()
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_invalid(form)

    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

forms.py

```
class CreateCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CreateCommentForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method="post"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field("content",css_class="form-control",style="margin-bottom:10px",rows="1"),
        )
        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit','Comment',css_class="btn btn-sm",style="background-color: #0d6ec5;border-color: #0d6ec5;"))



    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'content'
        ]
```

II. It worked from my admin panel but not from my website (I got this error: (1048, “Column 'user_id' cannot be null”)).
So I've decided to change my models with:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

The thing is if a user post a comment, content is ok but there is no user related to the comment. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `.user` attribute, probably to the logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post = self.object
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice. You mean this for the model?
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

I've tried to use your code in my view but it makes the detail only available for user. I've use this to solve this issue:

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% crispy form %}  
  {% else %}
  <p>Already a member? Login in to comment!</a></p>
  {% endif %}
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

Comment: @Louis: if you change `models.ForeignKey(User,  ...)` to ``models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  ...)`, and the user model is `User`, that will not make any difference. You can drop the `LoginRequired` if you want to make the form accessible to non-users. But this is a bit "risky", since now non-logged in users can "forge" a request. In that case, you might want to use a different view to post the comment.

Comment: Yes I understand :) thanks. When I post a comment from. I got his error 
name 'request' is not defined. Any advice? Sorry I'm a beginner with Django

Comment: @Louis: sorry made a typo, it is `form.instance.user = self.request.user` instead of `... = request.user`.

Comment: Amazing :) thanks. I've created a UserProfile related to User with image like that: 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='user/')
...   
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 200 or img.width > 200:
            new_size = (200, 200)
            img.thumbnail(new_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I can display the related user image?

Comment: @Louis: `{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}` should normally give the url, so you can use `<img src="{{ urer.userprofile.image.url }}">` in the template.

Comment: @Louis: or for a specific `post`, `{{ post.user.userprofile.image.url }}`.

Comment: Thanks I don't need to use comment? For the comment if example leave a comment. 
<div class="box-comment">
    <div class="img-comment"><img src="{{ comment.user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="25px" height="25px" style="border-radius: 90px;background: #ffffff38;"></div>
    <div class="user-comment"><strong>{{ comment.user }}</strong><small>, {{ comment.publishing_date }}</small><p>{{ comment.content }}</p></div>
  </div>

Comment: @Louis: ah, for the image of the commentator, yes, then it is `{{ comment.user.userprofile.image.url }}`. As long as the item has a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField` to the suer, you can use that to obtain the user, and thus its `.userprofile`.